# Как в resource сделать вывод по slug

Tags: laravel

`Routes`

```
Route::resource('/news', 'NewsController');
```

Для просмотра новости есть путь `/news/id`

Как указать вместо `id` другое поле, например `slug`?

Указать выше `resource`

```
Route::get('/news/{slug}', 'NewsController@show');
```

В принципе работает, но есть еще редактирование/удаление и везде используется в адресе `id`

Или нужно прописывать все роуты отдельно, вместо `resource`

```
GET           /news                      index   news.index
GET           /news/create               create  news.create
POST          /news                      store   news.store
GET           /news/{slug}               show    news.show
GET           /news/{slug}/edit          edit    news.edit
PUT|PATCH     /news/{slug}               update  news.update
DELETE        /news/{slug}               destroy news.destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::resource('/news', 'NewsController', ['parameters' => [
    'news' => 'slug'
]]);
```